# Search and replace with back reference variables

Tags: linux, awk, grep

```
String text = "This is a very tiny test!!!"    
Pattern p = "this is a (.*) test.*"

Output o = "very tiny" (after search and replace)
```

I want to replace the pattern with the content inside the bracket (), which is indexed with $1. On Linux, what command can do this and how?

I have to do this at command line, since my file is several GB and can't be done in an editor.

Comment: Edited now and it's displayed correctly.

Comment: but it's still missing concise, testable sample input plus expected output plus what you've tried so far - that's far more important than the formatting. See [ask] if that's not clear and in particular notice the part abut providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU ***sed***:

```
s='This is a very tiny test!!!'
sed -En 's/this is a (.*) test.*/\1/ip' <<< $s
```

The output:

```
very tiny
```

---

`i` - The `I` modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU extension which makes sed match *regexp* in a case-insensitive manner.

---

Alternative ***perl*** approach:

```
perl -nle 'print $1 if /this is a (.*) test.*/i' <<< $s
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work,  sed -En 's/This is a (.*) test.*/\1/ip' <<< $test.txt. Anything wrong? It doesn't output anything.

Comment: @user697911, No, my approach deals with a text variable (as you posted in your question). To deal with a file use: `sed -En 's/This is a (.*) test.*/\1/ip' test.txt`